# How to convert hexString to SWT Color?

Tags: java, colors, hex, swt

When you have hexString `#FFF080` and you want to convert it to `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color`, what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply do this:

```
public static Color decode(Display display, String hexString)
{
    try
    {
        java.awt.Color c = java.awt.Color.decode(hexString);

        return new Color(display, c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndyTurner You're absolutely right, that is what I meant to di. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks you! It is better :)

Answer (score 3):

Of course! There are many other ways to solve that problem. 
Following is the one of solution.

```
public static Color decode(Display display, String hexString) {
            try {
                Integer intval = Integer.decode(hexString);
                int i = intval.intValue();
                return new Color(display, (i >> 16) & 0xFF, (i >> 8) & 0xFF, i & 0xFF);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

You can find above kind of implementation source code at `java.awt.Color.decode(str);`

Comment: @Thomas [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: I also doubt like that at first. But it is work with `#`.

Comment: @Thomas  I have problem, then I solved it my own. I want to document my answer and share it.  So, I posted Q&A. And I also want another better solution :)

Comment: Hmm, I still have the feeling that this aproach is already documented elsewhere (at least in `java.awt.Color.decode()` as you mentioned). I accept that this is a controversial topic and it might just be my personal feeling. Besides that you didn't ask for a better solution.

Comment: Whenever we post a question, do we need to request a better solution? I do not think so. If somebody has better solution, I think he will post it. Welcome! :)

Comment: @Alice I don't see why you would need to ask for a better solution. I agree that if someone thinks they know a better solution they will post it. The OP can then accept the answer s/he thinks fits best.